# Program is not printing information based on set conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this csv file named sample.csv:

```
CODE     Place     Time
0001       USA       00
0002    Canada       00
0003    Canada       01
0004       USA       01
0005    Canada       01
```

I want to print all information that are both "Canada" and "01".  So for the example above, I want to see this:

```
CODE     Place     Time
0003    Canada       01
0005    Canada       01
```

This is what I've coded but it isn't working (the compiler says "Empty DataFrame").  What should I change?

```
import pandas as pd

search_Place = "Canada"
search_Time = "01"

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df2 = df[df["Place"] == search_Place][df["Time"] == search_Time]

print(df2)
```

Comment: Empty Dataframe makes sense since what you are doing is `df["Place"] == "Canada"`, but as far as I know, `df["Place"]` returns a column and so you can't compare a column with a string. You will probably need to iterate over each column value and see for equality..

Comment: @SanjeevanKhanduri On contrary, yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `df[df["Place"] == search_Place]` has different length than (3) that of `df["Time"] == search_Time` (6, which is `len(df)`. I'd be surprised if your code (`df2 = df[df["Place"] == search_Place][df["Time"] == search_Time]`) doesn't throw an error/warning.

Try:

```
df[df['Place'].eq(search_Place) & df['Time'].eq(search_Time)]
```

Output:

```
   CODE   Place Time
2  0003  Canada   01
4  0005  Canada   01
```

Comment: I have tried this but the same error (Empty DataFrame) occurred.

Comment: Check for correct datatype. Do `print(df.dtypes)` to see if `Time` is string (object) type? Also check for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: According to what has been printed, time is int64.

Comment: That's you problem right there, your `search_Time` is the string `"01"`. Try `search_Time=1`.